# Custom color for boxplots in SAS using SGPLOT

Tags: sas, boxplot

The following code comes from SAS's website.

I'm using it to ultimately create boxplots, however I have two datasets with same "grouping" variable (with 5 categories/levels/options say A, B, C, D and E).

Currently, the code automatically applies color coding to the two graphical outputs and is unfortunately applying different color for the same category/level/option in the two datasets. e.g. in dataset1, it codes A with blue while in dataset2 it codes A with red.

I'd like to specify color schema so that same color is applied to a given category in both datasets. This helps in visualization.

```
  data lft;
       input test $ A B @@;
       datalines;
    ALAT      1.05198    0.97755  ASAT      0.78177    0.59554    ALKPH     0.20475    0.20589
    BILTOT    0.12868    0.10760  ALAT      1.00211    1.19132    ASAT      1.07368    0.85466
    ALKPH     0.69033    0.56213  BILTOT    0.38943    0.50285    ALAT      0.63396    0.53781
    ASAT      0.05348    0.14887  ALKPH     0.75340    0.07973    BILTOT    0.87345    0.44291
    ALAT      0.70381    0.81970  ASAT      1.03230    0.83068    ALKPH     0.42431    1.05635
    BILTOT    0.14320    0.54282  ALAT      0.23767    0.62809    ASAT      1.90154    1.76075
    ALKPH     0.41850    0.28345  BILTOT    0.54899    0.32524    ALAT      0.70693    0.89745
    ASAT      0.30255    0.47380  ALKPH     0.13230    0.28027    BILTOT    0.81690    0.14692
    ALAT      0.12827    0.37964  ASAT      0.80481    0.03603    ALKPH     0.18448    0.53166
    BILTOT    1.19420    0.35609  ALAT      0.82422    0.85656    ASAT      0.03430    1.25747
    ALKPH     0.21351    0.17765  BILTOT    0.32556    0.49431    ALAT      1.06820    0.28720
    ASAT      0.95546    1.11008  ALKPH     0.03092    1.04798    BILTOT    0.57001    0.03822
    ALAT      0.23055    0.77542  ASAT      0.10612    1.29305    ALKPH     0.03577    0.10963
    BILTOT    0.79160    0.28032  ALAT      0.78603    0.45259    ASAT      0.24872    0.96720
    ALKPH     0.50077    0.55558  BILTOT    0.38930    0.03795    ALAT      0.54711    2.20000
    ASAT      2.11348    0.77847  ALKPH     0.31640    0.04882    BILTOT    0.12872    0.48268
    ALAT      0.78600    0.46686  ASAT      0.24883    0.49811    ALKPH     0.03704    0.25468
    BILTOT    0.12923    0.17796  ALAT      0.48393    0.45078    ASAT      1.56288    1.35533
    ALKPH     0.43352    0.66135  BILTOT    1.06012    0.85799    ALAT      0.46068    0.25030
    ASAT      1.56448    0.52508  ALKPH     1.00876    0.57161    BILTOT    0.44817    0.19389
    ALAT      1.06331    0.00000  ASAT      1.38521    0.19008    ALKPH     0.35466    0.61868
    BILTOT    1.24180    0.04822  ALAT      0.48065    0.40992    ASAT      1.05618    0.78853
    ALKPH     0.19355    0.66358  BILTOT    0.73715    0.09852    ALAT      1.21493    0.64416
    ASAT      0.70453    2.51609  ALKPH     0.26489    0.33604    BILTOT    0.72164    0.33025
    ALAT      1.04961    0.97218  ASAT      0.32183    1.35889    ALKPH     0.03934    0.41986
    BILTOT    0.20788    0.12524  ALAT      0.11145    0.80421    ASAT      0.29223    0.94908
    ALKPH     0.00864    0.05148  BILTOT    0.08176    0.00000    ALAT      0.54881    0.48289
    ASAT      0.23306    0.33808  ALKPH     0.58716    1.01387    BILTOT    0.73317    0.01936
    ALAT      0.70290    0.42668  ASAT      0.60399    1.09609    ALKPH     0.27376    0.00000
    BILTOT    0.17014    0.16435  ALAT      0.90385    1.06340    ASAT      0.00000    1.04065
    ALKPH     0.19284    0.27968  BILTOT    0.02284    0.10508    ALAT      0.77662    0.27623
    ASAT      0.79289    0.78862  ALKPH     0.24560    0.33058    BILTOT    0.44045    0.52485
    ALAT      1.15780    0.11335  ASAT      0.96932    0.84560    ALKPH     0.07827    0.29355
    BILTOT    0.13112    1.50000  ALAT      0.50103    0.61329    ASAT      1.11541    0.08967
    ALKPH     0.74840    0.43341  BILTOT    0.47621    0.85664    ALAT      0.36086    0.50746
    ASAT      2.03550    1.30451  ALKPH     0.56854    0.43620    BILTOT    0.09094    1.26472
    ALAT      0.95770    0.63754  ASAT      2.03683    1.83280    ALKPH     1.40042    0.12018
    BILTOT    0.22545    0.43027  ALAT      0.32817    0.50025    ASAT      2.60000    0.24234
    ALKPH     0.13532    0.21778  BILTOT    0.55075    0.48568    ALAT      0.26668    0.45166
    ASAT      1.06058    0.83500  ALKPH     0.22807    0.62830    BILTOT    0.46843    0.16910
    ALAT      0.28617    0.55219  ASAT      0.30707    0.52809    ALKPH     0.55278    0.04707
    BILTOT    0.06412    0.37335  ALAT      0.28907    0.14920    ASAT      0.10258    0.75400
    ALKPH     0.00730    0.10016  BILTOT    0.47780    0.23071    ALAT      1.16461    0.92092
    ASAT      0.80571    0.22561  ALKPH     0.17983    0.62150    BILTOT    0.53452    0.77714
    ALAT      0.05326    0.51731  ASAT      1.09366    1.67147    ALKPH     0.56498    0.30936
    BILTOT    0.07047    0.34371  ALAT      1.05258    0.05138    ASAT      0.15650    0.38367
    ALKPH     0.09618    0.50434  BILTOT    0.59625    1.44028    ALAT      0.10204    0.33631
    ASAT      0.95273    0.15079  ALKPH     0.70621    0.06809    BILTOT    0.37559    0.92632
    ALAT      0.76055    0.72907  ASAT      1.36379    0.12393    ALKPH     0.03081    2.00000
    BILTOT    0.92652    0.19981  ALAT      0.95481    0.32130    ASAT      0.75320    2.50581
    ALKPH     0.23371    1.17739  BILTOT    0.30880    0.22500    ALAT      1.96947    0.05734
    ASAT      2.58784    0.21524  ALKPH     0.76119    0.48148    BILTOT    0.25826    0.52166
    ALAT      1.03068    0.14734  ASAT      2.44450    0.48403    ALKPH     0.34170    0.34804
    ;
    run;

    proc transpose data=lft out=lft2(rename=col1=value) name=drug;
       var a b;
       by test notsorted;
    run;

    title 'Distribution of Maximum Liver Function Test Values by Treatment';

    proc sgplot data=lft2;
       vbox value / category=test group=drug;
       xaxis label="Treatment";
       keylegend / title="Drug Type";
    run;
```

I came up with this template :

```
data test;
  length value FillColor LineColor $30;
  Id='X'; Value="A"; FillColor='Red'; LineColor='Black'; output;
  Id='X'; Value="B"; FillColor='Yellow'; LineColor='Black'; output;
  Id='X'; Value="Cevol_greater_OneYear"; FillColor='Green'; LineColor='Black'; output;
  Id='X'; Value="Cevol_Term_No_Longer_Use"; FillColor='Blue'; LineColor='Black'; output;
  Id='X'; Value="Cevol_DhartTirm"; FillColor='Orange'; LineColor='Black'; output;
run;


proc sgplot data=lft2 dattrmap=test;
           vbox value / category=test group=drug attrid=X;
           xaxis label="Treatment";
           keylegend / title="Drug Type";
        run;
```

When I apply the above, some of the categories are coded the same but some arent

Comment: What version of SAS are you using?

Comment: If SAS 9.3+ http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2014/10/19/consistent-group-colors-by-value/

Comment: Yes - using SAS 9.3. I've amended the question as I came up with some code, but when I run it - I get no graphical output at all. Its like a blank gray box

Comment: See the link above and data attribute map option.

Comment: I tried the code in the link, but it won't work accurately - I've updated the code as I applied to my datasets, also explaining what happens

Comment: Does your code align with your sample data?

Comment: Ok - i figured it out. It seems like the length of one of the variable names for the category is causing some issue. If I rename the category to a shorter name, it works fine. Not worth spending time figuring out the craziness. The above code works well

Comment: Awesome! You should post your working code as an answer, I'm sure someone else will have this question at some point.

Answer (score 1):

First image:
[image]

Second image:
[image]

Boxplots are colored correctly...